# Extracting requierement properties from Capella

Tags: m2doc

I would like to extract the requirements data in capella using m2doc, requirements (SystemFunctionalRequirement) are located in a "RequirementsPkg" package in System analysis, thanks to the "m:RequirementsPkg.eContents().summary" command I managed to retrieve the summary of all requirements but I would like to retrieve the name and the summary of a specific requirement.

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What have you tried already? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This mechanism is deprecated. You should use the requirement extension.

Starting from the root element, you can use something like:

{ m:system.ownedArchitectures->filter(la::LogicalArchitecture).ownedRequirementPkgs.ownedRequirements.name }

With the requirement extension the easiest way is to create a service:

```
    public List<Requirement> getRequirements(ExtensibleElement element) {
    List<Requirement> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ElementExtension extension : element.getOwnedExtensions()) {
        if (extension instanceof Requirement) {
            res.add((Requirement) extension);
            break;
        } else if (extension instanceof CapellaOutgoingRelation) {
            res.add(((CapellaOutgoingRelation) extension).getTarget());
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

and call it, for instance on a diagram:

{ m:for req | '[LAB] IFE System - All Components, CEs'.representationByName().eAllContents(viewpoint::DRepresentationElement).semanticElements->filter(emde::ExtensibleElement).getRequirements() }

- { m:req.ReqIFLongName }

{ m:endfor }